# Why doesn't accessing Task.Result throw an exception but Task.get_Result() does?

Tags: .net, powershell, exception, properties, task

Consider the following:

```
Add-Type @'
public class Thrower
{
    public string Throw()
    {
        throw new System.Exception("some exception");
        return "return value";
    }

    public System.Func<string> GetThrow
    {
        get { return Throw; }
    }
}
'@ -IgnoreWarnings

$t = [System.Threading.Tasks.Task[string]]::new([Thrower]::new().GetThrow)
$t.Start()
```

The [documentation for the `Task<TResult>.Result` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) includes the following statement:

> Note that, if an exception occurred during the operation of the task, or if the task has been cancelled, the Result property does not return a value. Instead, attempting to access the property value throws an AggregateException exception.

Based on that I expect that accessing `$t.Result` would throw an exception.  It does not.  However, invoking

```
try { $t.get_Result() } catch { throw $_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException }
```

outputs

```
some exception
At line:1 char:37
+ ... Result() } catch { throw $_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException }
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : some exception
```

Similarly, invoking

```
try { $t.Wait() } catch { throw $_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException }
```

outputs the same exception.

Cursory testing of [the analogous program in C#](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/510d3bffa7a54394259af6783d332393) seems to indicate that accessing `Task<TResult>.Result` indeed throws an exception in C#.

Why doesn't accessing `Task<TResult>.Result` in PowerShell throw an exception when `.get_Result()` and `.Wait()` do?